# No such file package.json when running npm i

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run the following commands:

```
npm i && npm run
```

I get the following error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Singh/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Singh/package.json'
npm WARN Singh No description
npm WARN Singh No repository field.
npm WARN Singh No README data
npm WARN Singh No license field.
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to run this command after you cloned something from GitHub?

Comment: I did clone something and downloaded the latest node.js package

Comment: What is your question? The error message seems pretty clear to me. There is no `package.json` in the directory you are in, so presumably you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks but I'm kinda new to using terminal commands so couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're in the wrong directory -- you're in your user directory. If you cloned something from a repository, make sure you navigate to that directory before running `npm i`:

```
cd path/to/cloned/project
npm i && npm run <script_here>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

First check there is package.json file or not if not create package.json file using `npm init`